# Using ADO.NET in UWP apps possible?

Tags: c#, sql, azure, ado.net, win-universal-app

I am trying to use ADO.NET so that my C# UWP app can access my Azure SQL database but when I try to refer to "System.Data.SqlClient", it is not readily available. I tried importing the "System.Data.dll" file but that led to a new host of errors.

I'm being led to believe that ADO.NET is not compatible with UWP apps. The problem with that is that I can't find another technology that will allow me to work with my Azure SQL database. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Such drivers are usually platform specific, instead expose the database via a web service over HTTP and interact with it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you possibly give me a hint for where I should start with that approach? From there I will do all of the research I need. Thanks.

Comment: web service is the way that I would go for this middle layer..

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to create a full web api solution.
So, at the end, you will have

1. An Azure SQL Database
2. A Web API website , which will expose your datas in a JSON format. Using Entity Framework is not mandatory but can help in some way :)
3. An UWP application which will request your Web API endpoints

You will find here a complete solution : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1

Answer (score 0):

Latest UWP platform offers connectivity to SQl Server .
Please refer 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases